# Is the collection of atlases on a set $X$ a set?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, manifolds

Well, the title says it all. I need to know if i can view the collection of all atlases on a given set $X$ as a ordinary set. Is this possible ? All the atlases are only topological atlases, no additional structure.

Thanks in advance!! Greetings...

Comment: Is the dimension known?

Comment: The detailed answer is given below: the general answer is that given that you know Russell's paradox you will almost certainly never construct something that's not a set without it being obvious to you that you've done so. The bound in the answer shows the set of atlases is actually quite tiny, albeit possibly bigger than most sets we encounter.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Yes, the dimension for the collection of atlases is fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the charts are to $\mathbb{R}^k$ then it is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^k\times \mathcal{P}(X))$, by identifying a chart with a pair $(f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}^{k},U \subset X)$. If the dimension is not fixed a priori, then replace $\mathbb{R}^k$ with $\mathbb{R}^* = \bigsqcup_{k \ge 0} \mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: Thank you !! But i believe that there is an extra $\mathcal{P}$ in your answer, isn't it ?

Comment: @onebengaltiger the set of atlases is a set of set of charts. The inside $\mathcal{P} $ is because an open set is a subset of $X$.

Comment: I mean the first $\mathcal{P}$, i believe it should be $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^X \times \mathcal{P}(X))$ instead of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^X \times \mathcal{P}(X)))$

Comment: @onebengaltiger as I said in my previous comment, it's a *set of sets of* charts, not a set of charts.